# find the minimum value of X that satisfies the expression (A|X)&(B|X)=C

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, minimum

How to find the minimum value of X that satisfies the expression (A|X)&(B|X)=C for given A,B,C. If no such X exists, return -1

`|` bitwise or operator, `&` bitwise and operator

I am not sure how to approach this question. The simplest, brute force way is to loop through every X and put it in the equation which times out as expected.

However, the given boolean expression can be simplified to just (A&B)|X = C.

From this, I could easily calculate A&B and converted it into binary. I also converted C to binary.

My approach:

1. Go through each bit of A&B.
   If it is 1 and the corresponding bit of
   C is 0, return -1 since you cannot OR 1 with anything to return 0
2. Else add the bit of C to X.

I don't know if this is the best approach or even results in the minimum value. It does find an X that solves the expression but not sure if it's the best X.

```
def minXFinder(A,B,C):
   bits = bin(A&B)[2:]
   C_bits = bin(C)[2:]
   bits='0'*(len(C_bits)-len(bits))+bits
   C_bits='0'*(len(bits)-len(C_bits))+C_bits
   X = ''
   for i in range(len(bits)):
       if bits[i] == '1' and C_bits[i] == '0':
           return -1
       else:
           X+=C_bits[i]

   X=int(X,2)
   return X,(A|X)&(B|X)==C
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: note that if `a&b=1` and `c=1`, then you don't need `1` in `x` and can leave it `0` thus minimizing the result.

Comment: @gog that is a good observation

Comment: With your code, `minXFinder(1,1,3)` returns `(3, True)`. But you can achieve the equation with `X=2` because `(1|2) & (1|2) = 3`. So I think there is some problem in this implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Given `A,B,C`, we want to find the smallest nonnegative integer `X` such that `(A|X)&(B|X) = C`. As pointed out, this can be rewritten as `(A&B)|X = C`.

Let us consider the brute force approach first. Observe that if `X` exists, then this should not be greater than `C`. This is because, if `X > C`, then there exists at least one bit where `X` has 1 and `C` has 0. This bit will also be 1 in `(A&B)|X`, which contradicts the equality condition.
As a result, we only need to search `X` from zero to `C` to find the solution.

```py
def f1(A,B,C):
  # brute force
  AandB = A&B
  for X in range(C+1):
    if AandB|X == C:
      return X
  return -1
```

To seek a more efficient approach, consider the bitwise relations we need to have the equality requirement.

- If a bit in `A&B` and `C` are both 1, then `X` does not affect the result (the left hand side is 1 anyways). Since we want to minimize `X`, we want 0 in such cases.
- If `A&B=1` and `C=0`, then the left hand side will be 1 for any `X`, hence we cannot satisfy the equality condition.
- If `A&B=0` and `C=1`, then we need to have `X=1` to satisfy the equality.
- If `A&B=0` and `C=0`, then we need to have `X=0` to satisfy the equality.

This is summarized as below.

| A&B | C | X |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | - |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |

So, we first check if there is a bit where `A&B` has 1 but `C` has 0. If so, the condition cannot be satisfied.
Next, we want 0 if `(A&B,C) = (0,0) or (1,1)`, and 1 if they are not equal. This is actually `XOR` relation (`^` in python), which returns `true` when exactly one of them is true.
This observation leads us to the below function:

```py
def f2(A,B,C):
  AandB = A&B
  if AandB & (~C) != 0:
    return -1
  return C^AandB
```

The script below verifies that the two functions are identical for inputs smaller than 100, and the desired equation is satisfied.

```py
for A in range(100):
  for B in range(100):
    for C in range(100):
      assert f1(A,B,C) == f2(A,B,C), (A,B,C)
      X = f2(A,B,C)
      if X >= 0:
        assert (A|X)&(B|X) == C, (A,B,C)
```